# Trying to rotate the secondary screen counter clockwise but main screen crashes

Tags: display

After installing elementary, I tried to rotate my secondary screen, as the title implies.

However, as I followed my instincts and navigated myself to the display settings in the system settings window and applied my changes on my secondary screen, the main screen always gets distorted.

I don't know what to do, I have installed the updates and looked for drivers for my AMD 290X, but that should have been covered in my regular software update, right?

Anyone know what I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it via Command Line:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right
```

Comment: The issue remains, I suspect that this is the command called by the GUI.